# Laravel 5.1 relationship not working when using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a store and a comments model set up, and I've created a relationship that should return all of the store comments concatenated together. This is working fine until I attempt to use eager loading, then the relationship will always return NULL.

This is the relationship:

```
  public function FormattedStoreComments()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Models\StoreComment','StoreID','StoreID')
              ->select(DB::raw("group_concat(DATE_FORMAT(StoreComment.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'), ' - ', ShortName, ' - ', Comment, '\n'  ORDER BY StoreComment.created_at DESC SEPARATOR '') as Comments"))
              ->join('users','StoreComment.created_by','=','users.UserID')
              ->groupBy('StoreID')
              ->whereNull('StoreComment.deleted_at')
              ->orderBy('StoreComment.created_at','DESC');
}
```

Is there any reason why this shouldn't be working with eager loading?

Comment: share ur controller too can u?

Answer (score 0):

Using Eloquent scopes, Try this:

```
   public function scopeFormattedStoreComments($query)
   {
    return  $query->hasOne('App\Models\StoreComment','StoreID','StoreID')
          ->select(DB::raw("group_concat(DATE_FORMAT(StoreComment.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d'), ' - ', ShortName, ' - ', Comment, '\n'  ORDER BY StoreComment.created_at DESC SEPARATOR '') as Comments"))
          ->join('users','StoreComment.created_by','=','users.UserID')
          ->groupBy('StoreComment.StoreID')
          ->whereNull('StoreComment.deleted_at')
          ->orderBy('StoreComment.created_at','DESC');
   }
```

and then you can call it like this :

```
$formattedStoreComments = Store::formattedStoreComments()->get();
```

Comment: Good spot, but unfortunately no change.

Comment: Please set us the error message in your browser console

Comment: I'm using 'return dd($store->FormattedStoreComments);' in the controller to show the comment. Without eager loading the comment is there, however with eager loading it just shows null.

Comment: If I add the ->get() I get the error: BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: Ok, as I see you have Store hasone StoreComment in your models?

Comment: Yeah, the FormattedStoreComments relationship is in the store model.

Comment: With ->first() I get the error: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2099:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()